# What is the meaning of step (e) in the prioritized sweeping algorithm? Why is P calculated like that?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, prioritized-sweeping

Following is the "Prioritized Sweeping" algorithm in Sutton-Barto's RL book (page 170).  What is the meaning of step (e) in the prioritized sweeping algorithm? More importantly, why is P calculated like that?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$P$ tells you how "off" the evaluation for $Q(S, A)$ is. If the difference between $Q(S,A)$ (current best guess) and $R + \gamma\max_a Q(S', a)$ (update-value for $Q(S, A)$ since you received $R$ and were moved to $S'$ when you did $A$) is large, then it is an indication that this is a state-action-pair you should consider to learn more about, and $(S, A)$ will be close to the front of the queue. On the other hand, if $P$ is small, there is "nothing new to learn", and no need to prioritize this state-action-pair.